# Self-accept should not show up in reputation tab events

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, self-answer

[image]

See screenshot.  The event shows up with a green `0` in the left hand column.  Probably it shouldn't show in this table at all, since it is not an event that can influence the reputation.

Comment: Why not? The reputation table shows events for votes after you've reached the reputation cap.

Comment: It doesn't show them with a "0" in the left column though.

Comment: 0 is only shown in this case because we keep the green background for the accept to match, but a green background with nothing in it looks odd.

Answer (score 4):

The normal expectation is that the reputation table shows all events related to the award of reputation (up-votes, down-votes, accepted answer, etc). If we eliminated specific instances where no reputation is actually awarded, there's no way to know that those event are actually accounted for. In other words, users would ask why those entries are missing — e.g. *"Why doesn't the 'accepted answer' show up here?"*

By including those non-qualifying activities, you can see that all the events have been accounted for (even when no reputation is actually awarded). This is consistent with showing up-votes (for example) even after the user has hit their daily reputation cap.

See here: [**Jon Skeet reputation (not) earned after his reputation cap has been reached**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=time)

Comment: That seems inconsistent to me - a self-accept event is not (and as far as I know, never was) related to award of reputation.  And an inventory of all accepts is already available in another tab [`all actions -> accepts`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim?tab=activity&sort=accepts).

Comment: @wim The list includes accepted answers. For users not privy to these discussions, the difference between a self-accepted answer and regular accepted answers is too nuanced for the average user to simply understand intrinsically. For them, there's nothing inconsistent about it.